# ArchLinuxでpostgresqlのクライアントツール(psql)だけをインストールしたい

Tags: linux, postgresql

ArchLinuxを利用しています。(サーバAと呼びます。)
PostgreSQLを別のサーバBに立てており、
このサーバの操作をサーバA側からリモートから行いたいです

しかしサーバA側ではPostgreSQLを使いたいとは思っておらず
`extra/postgresql` を入れるとパッケージ容量などが無駄になりそうです。
またインストールされていることで
間違えてpostgresqlを起動したままにしてしまう、
使っているpostgresqlの場所を間違える、などの問題もありそうです。

そこでpsqlコマンドをpostgresqlパッケージを使わずにインストールする手段はありませんか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

psqlコマンドは`extra/postgresql-libs`パッケージに含まれているようです。

https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/postgresql-libs/

`postgresql`の依存パッケージになっているので、PostgreSQLをインストールすると一緒にインストールされるのでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます！そういうことだったんですね。依存関係の調査方法を知ろうと思いました